# Which Scala version does Spark 2.4.3 uses?

Tags: apache-spark

I installed Scala(Version 2.12.8) and Spark(2.4.3) on my Mac OS from homebrew. I already have Java 1.8 installed on my machine.

When I launch spark-shell, I see the logo says:

Spark version 2.4.3, Using Scala version 2.11.12 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_144)

Why does is says  Scala version 2.11.12 instead of Scala(Version 2.12.8) which installed on my machine?

Does Spark 2.4.3 come with Scala 2.11.12?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in [the release notes](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-4-3.html):

> Spark 2.4.3 is a maintenance release containing stability fixes. This release is based on the branch-2.4 maintenance branch of Spark. We strongly recommend all 2.4 users to upgrade to this stable release.
>
> Note that 2.4.3 switched the default Scala version from Scala 2.12 to Scala 2.11, which is the default for all the previous 2.x releases except 2.4.2. That means, the pre-built convenience binaries are compiled for Scala 2.11. Spark is still cross-published for 2.11 and 2.12 in Maven Central, and can be built for 2.12 from source.

Additionally Scala version you happen to have on your machine is completely irrelevant - Spark uses Scala version that has been used to compile it.

Comment: Do you guys know why they switched back to 2.11?

Comment: Probably because they realized switching major Scala versions (which are binary incompatible) in a minor point release of Spark was a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

Once we start writing spark code, we need to import spark-core and spark-sql in project. If right versions are not installed, code compilation or runtime fails with missing definitions.

To choose the right version of spark and scala libraries:

See the spark version installed by running the spark-shell. It shows the spark and scala versions both. Use those versions only while importing in projects.

For example in SBT: Spark 2.4.5 supports 2.11.12 of scala

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.5"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"